# No module named sympy

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, sympy

Hi I'm learning linear algebra with python with an Edx course. (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ULAFF/notebooks/tree/may-14-2014/).

On "02.4.2.10 Practice with matrix-vector multiplication" with the first box, the code is:

```
import generate_problems as gp
print("What is the result of the matrix vector product below?")

p = gp.Problem()

p.new_problem()
```

generate_problems is a module that the professor at Edx created. However, I got an error importing sympy.

I got the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-79d56e0988cb> in <module>()
----> 1 import generate_problems as gp
      2 print("What is the result of the matrix vector product below?")
      3 
      4 p = gp.Problem()
      5 

/Users/user/Desktop/Course/Python/ipython/notebooks-master/generate_problems.py in <module>()
      2 from numpy import matrix
      3 
----> 4 from sympy import init_printing, Matrix, MatMul, latex, Rational, zeros
      5 from IPython.display import Math
      6 

ImportError: No module named sympy
```

I downloaded and installed sympy and it works in sympy directory in the terminal(Mac OS X yosemite) if I import.Could someone help me?

Comment: Maybe, python dist path is not associated yet with sympy path.

Comment: @duffymo, are you looking at a different question? The error clearly states `ImportError: No module named sympy` and it fails after having successfully executed `from numpy import matrix`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given that you are new to Python I would advise that you install a distribution that already includes the complete scientific python stack such as [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) or [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads). If it is specifically sympy you are after you can play around online at [Sympy live](http://live.sympy.org/). If you want to stick to your distribution try installing sympy with

```
pip install sympy
```

rather than downloading it manually.

Comment: Thank you! I installed Anaconda and it's really great :) Solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

you can also do it in the **jupyter notebook**. Write in a cell this, and Run that cell:

```
!pip install --upgrade
!pip install sympy 
import sympy
```

If your kernel uses python3, then use "pip3" instead. You may have to do Kernel->Restart, if it doesn't work straight away.

If it still doesn't find the module because Jupyter doesn't load the correct folder where it is installed. then consider doing either

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my/path/to/module/folder') 
#the (successful) line "!pip install sympy " should tell you where this path is
```

or (on the bash terminal)

```
echo "PYTHONPATH=\"$PYTHONPATH:my/path/to/module/folder\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# then restart jupyter notebook
```

Comment: How can I find the module's path?

Comment: @Elborito sorry for the late answer. that depends on (1) your OS, (2) the python package installer you have (pip2, pip3, conda2-3, others). whatever it is you should look for the "site-packages" folder. it contains the packages installed. I have anaconda, mine is "C:\Users\angelo\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to import a module function like

```
from sympy.solvers.ode.subscheck import checkodesol, checksysodesol
```

The IPython terminal throws
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy.solvers.ode.subscheck'; 'sympy.solvers.ode' is not a package`. But the same command was working in my Anaconda terminal while running Python.
It turned out both were different versions of **Sympy**. Actually, I had cloned the git repository and setup the latest dev version while the IPython was using the version in the `site-package` directory of Anaconda which didn't have the module I was trying to import.