# No module named sympy in pypy task

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy, pypy

I tried to use pypy to accelerate python task

```
pypy  .....py
```

and I received the following error message

```
from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation, PermutationGroup
ImportError: No module named sympy
```

According to [Use Sympy with Pypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949711/use-sympy-with-pypy)

```
pypy -m pip install sympy
```

should work.

I type the above command, it tells me

```
/usr/bin/pypy: No module named pip
```

I have installed pip, i.e. which pip will lead to

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

What will be the problem?  And how to proceed pypy with symby? (I use ubuntu and python 2.7)

I also found 
[No module named sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275418/no-module-named-sympy)
pip install sympy gives me
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): sympy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: You need to install pip for pypy. See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566676/failed-to-install-pip-for-pypy-on-ubuntu) for help on that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried sudo pypy get-pip.py then pypy -m pip install sympy gives me "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/pypy/../../local/lib/pypy2.7/dist-packages/mpmath-0.19.dist-info'
"

Comment: Got it! sudo pypy -m pip install sympy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually

```
sudo pypy -m pip install sympy
```

did the trick